# R type III SS producing inconsistent results

Tags: r, anova

I've been using type III SS in R for years now seemingly without issue. But now I'm having an issue with type III sums of squares in R producing highly inconsistent results with the car package.

Yes, I run this line of code every time.

```
options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))
```

The model I'm using is this:

```
M1 <- aov(Response ~ Location + Time + Fish*Nutrient, data=data)
Anova(M1, type="III")
```

Location (2), Time (3), Fish (3), and Nutrient (3) are all categorical variables (# levels in parentheses). If these categorical variables are listed as numbers in the data file, I run (one example):

```
data$Fish <- as.factor(data$Fish)
```

These are the results I get with SAS:

```
          Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
Location      13.122  1  22.08   <.0001 
Time          15.746  2  7.87    <.0001 
Fish          25.876  2  12.94   <.0001 
Nutrient      22.074  2  11.04   <.0001    
Fish:Nutrient 13.780  4  3.44    0.0006
```

When I initially ran this in R I had Nutrient and Fish with all numeric values for each level and ran as.factor for each variable and received these results:

```
          Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   56.827  1 95.6078 2.758e-13 ***
Location      13.122  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.746  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          24.682  2 20.7632 2.531e-07 ***
Nutrient       0.424  2  0.3567 0.7017240    
Fish:Nutrient 13.780  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.313 51
```

The only variables above that are different are Fish and Nutrient, and the same goes for each iteration below.

I then went in and made one minor change to the datasheet, changing one of the three levels of fish (originally 0, 1, 2) to (z, 1, 2). The output changed to this:

```
               Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)    5.3556  1  9.0104 0.0041488 ** 
Location      13.1220  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.7462  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          24.6825  2 20.7632 2.531e-07 ***
Nutrient      17.7692  2 14.9477 7.780e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.7799  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.3134 51
```

A huge change! And the output does not change based on whether or not I run as.factor for these new levels.

I then changed another level of Fish (now: z, o, 2) and the output only slightly changed to:

```
               Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)    7.6351  1 12.8455 0.0007557 ***
Location      13.1220  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.7462  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          24.6825  2 20.7632 2.531e-07 ***
Nutrient      17.6604  2 14.8562 8.243e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.7799  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.3134 51
```

After changing the last level of Fish (z, o, t) the output changed slightly to:

```
               Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)    5.3556  1  9.0104 0.0041488 ** 
Location      13.1220  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.7462  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          24.6825  2 20.7632 2.531e-07 ***
Nutrient      17.7692  2 14.9477 7.780e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.7799  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.3134 51
```

The above output is identical to the last three that I display below.

Then I moved to manipulate Nutrient (originally: 0, 4, 8) while keeping Fish at the new levels (z, o, t). I first changed Nutrient to (c, 4, 8):

```
              Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   27.783  1 46.7425 9.854e-09 ***
Location      13.122  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.746  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          14.578  2 12.2628 4.484e-05 ***
Nutrient      17.769  2 14.9477 7.780e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.780  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.313 51
```

Changing two levels (c, f, 8):

```
                  Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   51.708  1 86.9940 1.313e-12 ***
Location      13.122  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.746  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish           0.396  2  0.3332 0.7182029    
Nutrient      17.769  2 14.9477 7.780e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.780  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.313 51
```

Another huge change!

And three levels (c, f, e) results in another huge change in Fish, with the closest results to those of SAS:

```
               Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)    5.3556  1  9.0104 0.0041488 ** 
Location      13.1220  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.7462  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          24.6825  2 20.7632 2.531e-07 ***
Nutrient      17.7692  2 14.9477 7.780e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.7799  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.3134 51
```

Location was also originally a numeric variable with two levels (1, 2). So I then changed one level (y, 2):

```
              Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   24.474  1 41.1763 4.535e-08 ***
Location      13.122  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.746  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          24.683  2 20.7632 2.531e-07 ***
Nutrient      17.769  2 14.9477 7.780e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.780  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.313 51
```

And then two levels (y, z):

```
               Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)    5.3556  1  9.0104 0.0041488 ** 
Location      13.1220  1 22.0767 2.020e-05 ***
Time          15.7462  2 13.2459 2.328e-05 ***
Fish          24.6825  2 20.7632 2.531e-07 ***
Nutrient      17.7692  2 14.9477 7.780e-06 ***
Fish:Nutrient 13.7799  4  5.7959 0.0006352 ***
Residuals     30.3134 51
```

No change there when manipulating Location and the same goes for Time. So, why are my results for Location, Time, and the Fish:Nutrient interaction consistent throughout all of this and identical to that from SAS, yet the results for Fish and Nutrient constantly changing and never the same?

It seems that something has to be wrong that such huge changes are occurring with only slight changes to the datasheet, which themselves should have no impact on the results anyway. I've made every effort to run the above  models under the exact same conditions, with the only changes being those to the datasheets I mention.

Also note that I've been able to replicate the issue with a similar set of variables and levels, using similar manipulations of completely made up data.

Comment: If you still wanted an answer to this 4.5 years later, you could post a [mcve] ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if R might be using ordered factors here, so changing the level names will change the ordering (alphabetical by default) and hence the fit. Try `data$Fish <- factor(data$Fish,ordered=FALSE)` - and for Nutrient too. If Location only has two levels it won't matter, and Time should probably be ordered anyway.